# Any potential issues with running traces on both sides to increase conductivity?

Tags: pcb-design, trace

I have a few relays on my circuit board, they are classed as 10A 30VDC. The size and thickness of the traces I can create on my PCB is nowhere near that so I am thinking of running a parallel track on the other side of the PCB along with a few vias to increase the conductivity. Are there any concerns around this solution?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The track does not need to be big enough to deal with the relays. The track needs to be big enough to deal with the load you place on it, and protected against higher loads than that.

This means you need to specify a maximum current that the board is expected to handle. It might be 10 A to match your relays, it might be less. Design with enough track width to match this current. If you cannot get it all onto one layer, it's OK to split it between several layers and stitch through with vias. Make sure there are enough vias so that the current is indeed shared between the tracks, without the vias becoming hot-spots.

Finally, put a fuse on the high current inlet to the board, to protect the track against accidental over current.

Comment: Thanks Neil! Exactly what i needed to know. Basically i would like to allow for as high current as possible to give more flexibility and reduce the need for adding an external relay to handle higher loads.

Comment: One thought though, both relay and terminal block has connectors on both sides, is it still recommended to use a few vias? Not sure if there could be some issues around potential difference if they are running separate under load.

Comment: If both ends of the high current path use through hole terminals, and you can solder both sides, the vias are not needed. Run the tracks on the same path, and compute the current based on the minimum width of the track. They do not need to be the same width as each other, as the current will divide between them in ratio of the width.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for clarifying that, much appreciated!